# How to upload images and metadate using Codeigniter Rest Api

Tags: php, database, file, server, file-transfer

We are trying to upload images along with some metadata using a single REST api, the body of the request should contain both the file and other fields. Normally we use JSON in the bodies. How should we incorporate both the file and other information into a JSON object. In other words, how should the structure of the api body look like